# Passing a start and end date from my list to a map function to filter an ImageCollection in GoogleEarthEngine

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-2, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

For my script I have created the list `interval` where start and end dates are given for specific time intervals. I would like to `map` through that list to create a new list where I have an `ImageCollection` for each time interval. I managed to do that using a loop function but I would like to do it the "proper" way by using a `map-function`.

My problem is that I can't pass access the `start/end date` separately inside the function by using `dates[0]/date[1]`.
Anyone know how I could solve this problem?

```
var st_shp = geometry;

var imageIndex = function(image){
  image = image.normalizedDifference(['B8','B4']);
  return(image);
}; // Calculate NDVI

var sentinelCollection = function(dates) {
  var s2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
  .filterBounds(st_shp)
  .filterDate(dates[0],dates[1])
  .filterMetadata('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE','less_than',40);
  s2 = s2.map(function(x){return x.clip(st_shp);});
  s2 = s2.map(function(x){return imageIndex(x);});
  return s2;
}; // Create ImageCollection


var interval = ee.List([['2019-03-01', '2019-03-15'],['2019-03-15', '2019-03-29'],['2019-03-29', '2019-04-11']]);

var s2Collection = interval.map(sentinelCollection).flatten();
```

My think my problem is connected to the question that was raised here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47102922/double-loop-with-map-function-in-google-earth-engine

Answer (score 1):

These client-side lists with start/end dates get converted into server-side `ee.List` objects. You have to do two things. Cast the dates inside of your mapped function into `ee.List`, and extract start and end dates using `ee.List.get()`.

```
var sentinelCollection = function(dates) {
  dates = ee.List(dates)
  var s2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
  .filterBounds(st_shp)
  .filterDate(dates.get(0),dates.get(1))
  .filterMetadata('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE','less_than',40);
  s2 = s2.map(function(x){return x.clip(st_shp);});
  s2 = s2.map(function(x){return imageIndex(x);});
  return s2;
};
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/ca4fe2e8ce04354f716df4bf1f05966a

Comment: Thanks you so much! The problem now seems to be that the ImageCollection contains no images - or the images are considered as unknown elements